# Flask return image object

Tags: python, react-native, opencv, flask, api-design

I have a React Native project where I send a photo to my Flask backend to do some image processing, then return the processed image back to React Native (using a POST request for this entire process).

I am able receive the image into my Flask app, and am able to run the processing, however, I cannot figure out how to send the image back to React Native. So far I have tried everything without storing the image anywhere but I'm starting to wonder if I should create a temporary image file in flask (what would be the pros and cons)?

Here is what I have so far:

**app.py (Flask)**

```
@app.route('/analyze-img', methods=['POST'])
def analyze_img():
    # read image file
    filestr = request.files['FrontProfile'].read()
    npimg = np.frombuffer(filestr, dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv.imdecode(npimg, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    # process image
    img_annotated = process_img(img)

    # return output image
    retval, buffer = cv.imencode('.jpg', img_annotated)
    response = make_response(buffer.tobytes())
    return response
```

However, this returns undefined in the response for some reason (I have check the data going into Flask is fine):

```
const photo = { uri: frontProfile, type: "image/jpeg", name: "photo.jpg" };
var form = new FormData();
form.append("FrontProfile", photo);

await fetch("http://<my IP>:5000/analyze-img", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form,
})
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

which returns `JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"` Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi Ken, I am not sure what "*this returns undefined in the response for some reason*" means ?

Comment: Thanks, what I mean is when I read the response data in react native (after using fetch) its undefined, I will add an edit above

Comment: What method are you using in react native to read the response data ?

Comment: I have edited my question above to include how I read the response but I used response.json() which returns an error because response is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in: `response = make_response(buffer.tobytes())` line. As per the [make_response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) documentation,

> make_response(rv) Convert the return value from a view function to an
> instance of response_class.
>
> Parameters rv –
>
> the return value from the view function. The view function must return
> a response. Returning None, or the view ending without returning, is
> not allowed. The following types are allowed for view_rv:
>
> str (unicode in Python 2) A response object is created with the string
> encoded to UTF-8 as the body.
>
> bytes (str in Python 2) A response object is created with the bytes as
> the body.
>
> dict A dictionary that will be jsonify’d before being returned.

Since you are passing the byte object to this method, the `make_response` is not implicitly converting to a JSON format, which you are expecting on the client side. This can be fixed by using: `response = make_response({"payload": buffer.tobytes()}, 200)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing this but I got the following error: `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Please try type casting it `str` before constructing JSON

Comment: awesome thanks, now it seems like its returning something back to the frontend but do you know how I can recreate the image now in the frontend?

Comment: Yes, you are sending the encoded image to the client, you will need to decode the image at React Native side, using OpenCV or some other image lightweight de-compression library.